# autocomplete slug field in createView

Tags: python, django, generics

i made form to create post at blog site, but i need to autocomplete slug of post. i tried:

*views*

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PostCreationForm
    template_name = 'blog/create_post.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.slug = self.request.title

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

*forms*

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'tags', 'text', 'time_to_read', 'image', 'is_published', ]

        widgets = {
            'text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'time_to_read': forms.NumberInput(),
            'image': forms.FileInput()

        }
```

*models*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='post_tags')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_to_read = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

but with this i got WSGI error

thanks for help

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'slug'

Comment: The request form does not have a slug field. You might want to create a slug field on your model before calling `save` using `slugify` on another field.

Answer (score 0):

form.instance.slug = slugify(form.instance.title)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).